# Entity Framework - how to model this entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables where I want to store data for Product and its productivity. There is possibility to have multiple types of Productivities, but lets assume I have 3 (A, B and C). 
How can I store them in one table and only differentiate them by type and when it is loaded into entities they would be grouped by types?

```
ProductId   ProductivityTypeId  AddedDT Projected   Actual
1               1          2019-09-20   1000.000    900.000
1               2          2019-09-25   0.800       0.750
2               1          2019-09-20   1000.000    900.000



 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Productivity> ProductivityA { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Productivity> ProductivityB { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Productivity> ProductivityC { get; set; }
}

    public class Productivity
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public byte ProductivityTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset AddedDT { get; set; }
    public decimal Projected { get; set; }
    public decimal Actual { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductivityType ProductivityType { get; set; }
}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Productivity>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.ProductId, p.ProductivityTypeId, p.AddedDT });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ProductivityA).WithOne(p => p.Product);

    }
```

So I did try something like that :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ProductivityA).WithOne(p => p.Product).HasForeignKey(p => p.TypeId == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

for this problem, you can opt any of two approaches given below:

- you can use enums for productivity type like,
       public enum ProductivityTypes
        {
        TypeA=1, TYpeB, TypeC
        }
- You can have a composite key in the product table 
  for this please refer to this article:https://medium.com/radzenhq/how-to-entity-framework-core-relationships-composite-keys-foreign-keys-data-annotations-code-f4b238086463

Comment: Sorry I don't see how composite key would work? could explain more please? I'm interested with setting on model creation properties ProductivityA, B and C so they are filled with data from only this type

Comment: The composite key means your record will uniquely identifying by having two attributes as key i.e. in your query you have many to many relationships in your table so productID + ProductivitytypeID will become composite key. What you have done above is many to one relationship. One more suggestion to you is create enums for your productivity bcz in future if your productivity type change you need to change your table schema which is not right